# Accessing session between domain/subdomain. Local xampp installation

Tags: php, session, xampp

Thanks in advance.

I have a local installation of Xampp. My sites are setup as follows. I have my main domain i.e. 'domain' installatiopn directory: `C:\xampp\htdocs\domain`
Within this i have a subdomain setup i.e. '`subdomain.domain`' installation directory: `C:\xampp\htdocs\domain\subdomain`

The goal of this is to have a single sign on on the main domain site and be able to access the same session data when the user accesses the subdomain site (and thus not have to re-authenticate the user once they have logged into the domain portal site).

I create the session in my domain index.php as follows:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.3pccap'); 
session_name('mysessionname');
session_start();
```

Subdomain index.php

```
session_name('mysessionname');
session_start();
```

I've added a var_dump(`$_SESSION`); on each index.php page to confirm what session data is available. Once I log into my main domain, the session if populated with the users data. I then navigate to my subdomain site which also runs a var_dump of the session variable. The variable is displaying as an empty array.

I have attempted setting the session cookie domain within my php.ini file, no change in behaviour.

Any assistance is most appreciated.

Comment: How does the *Set-Cookie* directive look like?

Comment: Yes, i've checked within the following directory: C:\xampp\tmp and a new cookie is created when I log into the domain site.

A seperate cookie is also created when i access the subdomain site. Which i dont want to happen. My knowledge of cookies is poor though so im a little lost.

Comment: Set-cookie directive within my php.ini?

Comment: No, I meant the actual [HTTP header field *Set-Cookie*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Setting_a_cookie) that PHP generates in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the Session cookie visible for your subdomain (thus, calling the `session_set_cookie` on **both**, your domain and your subdomain):

```
session_set_cookie_params (0, '/', '.domain.com');
session_name('mysessionname');
session_start();
```

---

EDIT (From comments, which solved the issue)

A domain hostname should consist of two parts (even for local development), e.g. domain.local instead of domain

Comment: I have amended my pages so both the domain and subdomain call session_set_cookie_params (0, '/', '.domain.com');
session_name('mysessionname');
session_start();
when setting the session. I am still receiving an empty session array on my subdomain.

Comment: Do they both save the session data to the same path (e.g. check `phpinfo()`)?

Comment: phpinfo() session.save_path = C:\xampp\tmp for both my domain and subdomain.

Comment: What are the actual domain names you are using? A domain hostname should consist of two parts (even for local development), e.g. `domain.local` instead of `domain`

Comment: Ah ok, my domains were as stated above. So im assuming as the original domain was one word it was being treated as a top level domain (which i've read will not work)? I've amended this to domain.com and subdomain.domain.com and the cookie is correctly displaying the same session on both domains. Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 0):

When COOKIES are set, there is a parameter that allows you to specify the PATH and DOMAIN, if you set the DOMAIN to "domain.com" and the PATH to "/" this will make the COOKIE available accross all subdomains, some old browsers require the DOMAIN to use a leading dot(.) ".domain.com"...

[Checkout the params on this page](http://php.net/en/set_cookie), session_set_cookie_params also has the DOMAIN and PATH arguments