# joomla session object returns nothing

Tags: php, joomla

i have a form with the name field as below

```
<label class="control-label" for="name">Your Name *</label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="name" id="name" maxlength="10">
</div>
```

On form submit, i am trying to validate (server-side) the field in my controller as below:

```
function save(){               

      $name = JRequest::getVar('name', 'POST');

      $session =& JFactory::getSession();

      if(!$name || strlen($name = trim($name)) == 0){
         $session->set('errorname', 'Please enter your name!');
         $error= true;
      }
         $session->set('valuename', $name);

      if(!$error){

         $model = & $this->getModel('jobs');

         $model->saveJob(JRequest::get('POST'));

         $redirectTo = JRoute::_('index.php?option='.JRequest::getVar('option').'&task=display');
         $this->setRedirect(str_replace("&amp;", "&",$redirectTo), 'Saved');
      }
      else {                          
         $redirectTo = JRoute::_('index.php?option='.JRequest::getVar('option').'&Itemid='.JRequest::getVar('Itemid'));
         $this->setRedirect(str_replace("&amp;", "&",$redirectTo), "The form is not complete!" );                 
       }    

    }
```

Then again on top of my form page, i have tried to get the value of the session object **errorname** as below:

```
$session =& JFactory::getSession(); 
$session->get('errorname');
```

I am doing this just for test purpose; so, when i submit the form without filling the field then the session object should return an error (a message ***Please enter your name!***). But i wonder why nothing is returned.

I am not sure if i am missing something, please advice me!

Comment: $session =& JFactory::getSession(); remove space between & and jfacotry

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary Space between & Factory is no the issue,When you are working on server "subdomain" It may happend.Then correct the session path in library files of joomla

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @Jobin Jose but now session path issue is very new to me. how should i change it and what it actually does?

Comment: when your working with subdomain the session may not set properly .Bcoz in server  the session has specified path for storing it.You can find the file at libraries\joomla\session\session.php Also read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818129/accessing-session-between-domain-subdomain-local-xampp-installation

Answer (score 0):

It can be due to the reason that your if condition true part is not being executed.

```
if(!$name || strlen($name = trim($name)) == 0){
         echo 'works';die;
      }
```

Replace the code as above and check whether you get into the if condition true part. Other than that you are doing everything right. If the if condition is being evaluated right page will stop executing since `die;` command is used. This is a good way to make sure your code has not got errors.

[Read this link](http://www.tutsforu.com/c-language/8-joomla-tutorial/75-using-session-in-joomla.html). It will give you some of the usages of `JFactory::getSession()`

Comment: thankyou and i did as adviced by you and it works. what could be other possible reason?

Comment: i also applied the same approach inside  if(!$error){ }. In this case nothing happens.

Comment: check the link I have provided. There are some good examples. Anyway are you there any errors shown?

Comment: Try setting session value like this $session->set('valuename', 'Jhon doe'); Then try to retrive it $session->get('valuename');. Let me know  whether that works for you

Comment: print_r($session) on both pages and post the outputs separately.

Comment: haha .... its quite silly ... just check in my code that i have not echoed or printed the session object values. i tried echo $session->get('errorname');
echo $session->get('valuename'); it works

Comment: Thanks @Dasun for your kind help. Now one hurdle is over and i am thinking of another i.e passing each error and value to session is not a good practice. So, i wonder how i will add the errors in a session array object. For value i suppose i can do like $session->set('arr_values', JRequest::getVar('name', 'POST'));

Comment: use this method rather than using sessions http://docs.joomla.org/Display_error_messages_and_notices